# Voltage Follower vs Half Wave Rectifier

Tags: sine, precision-rectifier

So I used a voltage follower with an input of a sine wave signal (positive and negative cycle) . The output was half wave signal which is what I wanted. Why do people use half wave precision rectifier signal over a voltage follower. It seems a lot easier to just use a voltage follower. I am using a single power supply with Vcc- to GND.

Which is better for half wave signal rectification, a voltage follower or half wave rectifier?

[image]

Comment: how precise was it in mV compared to a true prec. rectifier?

Comment: What op-amp are you using?  What does the data sheet say about input voltages below its negative supply?

Comment: You might just as easily used a diode.

Comment: @Andyaka Using a diode, there will be a decrease in signal voltage whereas when I used Voltage follower, i did not see any decrease in voltage.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the voltage follower is not precise which I guess is the reason why half wave rectifier is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do people use half wave precision rectifier signal over a voltage
> follower.

In most applications using only a voltage follower and use the rail to do the clipping will leave common mode issues (the output may not approach zero or may distort or even hit the other rail). Below is an example, the blue trace is the output of the voltage follower, when the input goes negative, the output hits the positive rail.

Vout1 is the precision half wave rectifier (with the same opamp)
(I also inverted vout1 which is the output of the precision half wave rectifier so it doesn't lie on top of the other trace). There are rail to rail input and output amplifiers that could approach the performance of the precision half wave rectifier.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  I will take the common mode issue into consideration. As you have said, I might be using  a rail to rail opamp that is is capable of preforming close to the precision rectifier. I was able to get a good half wave signal using TSH82 opamp.